# returning values populated in an array from one function to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing a search through google maps, and I want to populate every location in an array. This allows me to sort properly since the API can lag at times and the JSON being returned may not be done correctly.

This is using the Google Maps Places API. Some code is left out to keep it brief. I'm able to get the array to populate within a function, but when I try to pass it to another function it's blank.

```
   var liquorSearchParams = {
        location: latLong,
        rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
        types: ['liquor_store']
    };

    //Call the google maps service to perform the search 
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(liquorSearchParams, callback);

   //Set my blank array
    var allPlaces = [];

    function callback(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          //createMarker(results[i]);
          addPlaceToArray(results[i]);
          //this console.log just shows []
          console.log(allPlaces);
        }

      }
    }

    function addPlaceToArray(place) {
        var placeIdRequest = {
          placeId: place.place_id
        };
        service.getDetails(placeIdRequest, placeDetailCallback);
    };

    function placeDetailCallback(placeDetail, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var destinationPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(placeDetail.geometry.location.k, placeDetail.geometry.location.B);
            var theDistance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(destinationPoint, latLong);

            allPlaces.push({name: placeDetail.name, latitude: placeDetail.geometry.location.k, longitude: placeDetail.geometry.location.B, address: placeDetail.vicinity, phone: placeDetail.formatted_phone_number, website: placeDetail.website, distance: theDistance});
            //this console.log returns the populated array that i want
            console.log(allPlaces);
            return allPlaces;
        }
    };
```

Comment: These functions are asynchronous. The second callback is not complete at the end of the first callback.

Comment: @MattR I guess I'm not following along. How do I get the second callback to complete before the first callback does?

Comment: Anything that relies on date from the second callback must be called from that function, or you can use a promise to call something after it has finished.

Comment: @MattR can you give me some pointers on how to learn how all this is accomplished? I don't have any exposure to asynchronous javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that this is happening because `allPlaces.push(...)` happens in a callback which happens **after** the `console.log(allPlaces)`.

Here the actual sequence of events as far as I can tell:

1. You retrieve some liquor stores
2. You iterate through them
3. For each store you:

   1. initiate a request for more details
   2. immediately do a `console.log(allPlaces)` - which is empty because step 3 hasn't happened yet
   3. when the request for more details finishes, you push the details to the `allPlaces` array.

What you need to do is do the `console.log(allPlaces)` once all the `placeDetailCallback`s have been completed. I recommend [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) or something similar.

Using Async.js:

```
var liquorSearchParams = {
    location: latLong,
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
    types: ['liquor_store']
};

var allPlaces = [];

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    async.each(results, addPlaceToArray, function(err) {
        // this gets executed when all places have been added to allPlaces
        console.log(allPlaces);
    });
  }
}

//This is called for each item in the results array
//The done parameter is a callback you call when you are, well, done.
function addPlaceToArray(place, done) {
    var placeIdRequest = {
      placeId: place.place_id
    };

    var placeDetailCallback = function(placeDetail, status) {
        var destinationPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(placeDetail.geometry.location.k, placeDetail.geometry.location.B);
        var theDistance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(destinationPoint, latLong);

        allPlaces.push({name: placeDetail.name, latitude: placeDetail.geometry.location.k, longitude: placeDetail.geometry.location.B, address: placeDetail.vicinity, phone: placeDetail.formatted_phone_number, website: placeDetail.website, distance: theDistance});
        done(); //if an error occurred here, you can pass it to done
    };

    service.getDetails(placeIdRequest, placeDetailCallback);
};

//Call the google maps service to perform the search 
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(liquorSearchParams, callback);
```

Comment: I put this code in and it's not working. I included the async.js file as well.

Here is the order of events that should happen:
1. Get Retrieve Stores
2. Iterate through each store
  2a. On each store, get the details for each one
  2b. Save the details in an array. This array will be used in a different function.

Comment: can you elaborate on "not working"? I didn't execute the code above, so there might be some syntax errors to work out

Comment: i'm sorry. that was a very unhelpful response from me. The console.log isn't outputting anything, as if the code never gets executed. Here is the gist with all the code. https://gist.github.com/kacole2/c8ad84bf51a2bbc88237

Comment: I'll take a look when I get a second... In the meantime, you should put this in a jsfiddle.

Comment: @KennyColeman - I created a JsFiddle that appears to be working (mostly): http://jsfiddle.net/f696vtzn/10/

I made some changes to get it to work on non-mobile and hard coded the location to NYC. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @Adam C. I'll see if I can get that code working here this afternoon. I appreciate the help

Comment: awesome! after a bit more hacking I've got it all working thanks to your JsFiddle @Adam C. If you have any resources on where to get learned up on Asynch JS I would appreciate it!